Is Peacemaker's mental precision in tracking time derived from the comics or unique to Suicide Squad Isekai?
In the 2024 anime series Suicide Squad Isekai, the members of the Suicide Squad are fitted with neck bombs that automatically detonate if they don’t receive an A.R.G.U.S. radio signal for 72 hours.
Interestingly, Peacemaker displays an impressive ability to keep track of time down to the second, showing impressive mental precision. He can state exactly how long remains until their neck bombs explode, without using any equipment. He first demonstrated this in episode 2 while imprisoned in the isekai world and continued to do so in later episodes.
Even Deadshot is taken aback by Peacemaker’s unexpected talent:

Deadshot: Holy crap. I didn’t think you actually had any brains in that head of yours.

I’m familiar with John Cena’s portrayal of Peacemaker in The Suicide Squad (2021) and the Peacemaker (2022) TV series, where he doesn’t show this ability. However, I don’t know much about the comic book version of the character, so I'm curious about its origin.
Is this impressive mental ability something Peacemaker displays in the comics, or is it unique to the anime's interpretation of the character?
